# Customize UIButton to make compatible to iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, iphone-5

I am working on my app to customize button accordingly. However once I change my button accordingly, now it has became irresponsive. You could see my code as follows. By the way, this button still works when I run on iPhone 4. It is really strange!
once I change my button position it works, but it wont work the position I want!

```
   float screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

   if(screenSizeHeight==568)
   [positionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(184,280,77,30)];

   if(screenSizeHeight==480)
   [positionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(184,240,77,30)];
```

Hand Bag button is not working!
[image: Hand Bag Button is not responding!]

Comment: use `bringSubviewToFront` for `positionButton`.

Comment: eventhough I change its place, still irresponsive! also [self.view bringSubviewToFront:positionButton]; still not working

Comment: You are changing x Position rite ? but width is same for both (320 only).. So..... Why do you have to change the xPostion

Comment: I am just changing x position .

Comment: Please see my updated question with screenshoot!

Answer (score 2):

Check your condition :

```
 if(screenSizeHeight==568)
```

In both cases you have used `screenSizeHeight == 568` so replace one with `screenSizeHeight = 480`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: or just an if { ... } ELSE { ... }

Comment: You are changing origin x only in both cases ?

Comment: I have checked you code. It is working fine at my end. You have done something wrong. Are you using AutoLayout ? If yes then it can also be the reason for this.

Comment: I am not using autolayout. It also works for other buttons, but not this button! I dont know why?

Comment: Can you do one thing. Create a new button and connect its outlet and then check is it still not working or working. It may work in this way.

Comment: @casillas Have you checked that in this way ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29520/discussion-between-nishant-tyagi-and-casillas)

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Default-568h.png` image get added or not. If it isn't added , you mainscreen returns bounds as `320x480`.

**Note :** 1) If you rotate device , check your main screen bounds. It may lead to confusion. You can try Better way to use it.

2) This `Default-568h.png` is only allowed when building an app using Xcode 4.5 and the iOS 6 SDK

3) When you ask a `UIScreen` for it's Bounds you get the bounds of the screen, which is the whole device screen. (the status bar is part of the screen)

Comment: I think this should not be the reason. Because he is setting frames for other buttons also. But in that case frame is changing.

Comment: default image added and works properly. Now, once I change my button position it works, but it wont work the position I want!

Comment: @NishantTyagi In his question he mention as, It is irresponsive in iPhone5. That means, iPhone5 Checks doesn't get true. So Frame doesn't change according to his question.

Comment: @casillas sorry I can see many button please mention which button`s frame to be change.

Comment: Just added this description on the top of the image.

Comment: I think you have to modify `Postion` Label frame also. Did you check `Use autoLayout` ? If yes, It leads to this error even you change any `y` of the button's frame.